# Gradle Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm getting some errors :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':gisett-backend:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gisett-backend:detachedConfiguration1'.
  > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE.
    Required by:
        project :gisett-backend
     > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE.
        > Could not get resource 'http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom'.
           > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom'.
              > No such host is known (repo.boundlessgeo.com)
     > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE.
        > Could not get resource 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom'.
           > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
```

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

It helped partially, now I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':gisett-backend'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':gisett-backend:classpath'.
  > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE.
    Required by:
        project :gisett-backend
     > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE.
        > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom'.
           > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

**Update 2:**
I fixed it (I updated a list of servers ) but now another error :

A problem occurred configuring project ':gisett-backend'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':gisett-backend:classpath'.
> Could not find io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
> - https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
> - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom

this is the part from build.gradle:

```
buildscript {


    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        //for finding propdeps-plugin dependency

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"

       // classpath 'io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE'

    }

}



//...


// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
//...

    maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}



}

//...
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your build.gradle should look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post: there are still errors.

Comment: I typed in the browser -  https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom it requires name and password

Comment: Refer the following link to configure spring boot with credentials

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/_configure_maven_properties.html

Comment: It does not work for me with the u_name (repo1user) and password (repo1pass).

Comment: I fixed it (I updated a list of servers ) but now another error.